# Web Deployment Using Accelerator

Tags: web-deployment-project, web-deployment

I am new to Azure Accelerator for web roles I have performed each step on the guidance from the net but I am getting an error when I try to deploy my website.Everything is rechecked by me WMSvc is running and is set to auto and username and password is correct but I dont understand where is the problem.

Error   1   Web deployment task failed.(Remote agent (URL http://2f96c9ab6cda4281bcf25a899d66955d.cloudapp.net/MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE) could not be contacted.  Make sure the remote agent service is installed and started on the target computer.)
Make sure the site name, user name, and password are correct. If the issue is not resolved, please contact your local or server administrator.
Error details:
Remote agent (URL http://2f96c9ab6cda4281bcf25a899d66955d.cloudapp.net/MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE) could not be contacted.  Make sure the remote agent service is installed and started on the target computer.
An unsupported response was received. The response header 'MSDeploy.Response' was '' but 'v1' was expected.
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.        0   0   QuickMVCdep

I am tired of this error please help me as soon as possible as my work is stopped because of this.